# Periodic function notation, need help with a fundamental concept

Tags: periodic-functions

Given the periodic function $x(t) = x(t+T)$, I would like to ask the following:

The textbook says that if the above function is valid then it is also valid for any $t$, that is $t+(k-1)T$.
If I could use an animation of a Cartesian axis to get a 'feeling' of it, what does it mean visually the $(k - 1)$? What is the difference if it is $k + 1$ or if it is just $k$ alone?  Maybe a shift ("delay/advance") in $t$ axis? which direction? **What is the meaning of $k-1$?** The $k-1$ is confusing me.
(Edited)

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the period of a function $x$·  In general, the graph of $x(t+T)$ is that of $x(t)$ shifted $T$ units to the left, but since $x$ is periodic with period  $T$,  translation of $T$ unit to the left and to the right are the same.  Since translation of $T$ unit to the left does not change the graph, such action performed $k-1$ times (gives the graph of $x(t+(k-1)T)$ and) leaves the graph unchanged.

Comment: '''In general, the graph of x(t+T) is that of x(t) shifted T units to the RIGHT,''...  Are you sure that x(t) shifts to the right? i plotted cos(x) and cos(x+10) it is shifted to the left.  I used geogebra(free online tool)

Comment: @DontAskTheEye You may want to see http://www.purplemath.com/modules/fcntrans.htm "Moving left or right"

Comment: i saw your link and i say thanks. So after seeing the website it says (close to the bottom of the page) that f(x+5) goes LEFT. so i suppose x(t+T) does NOT shift to the right as you have claimed. I am not trying to be rude to you i am trying to grasp the  concepts.

Comment: @DontAskTheEye Sorry for this careless mistake